# Is there any IDAPython API that returns the function which an address belong to?

Tags: ida, idapython

Given an address, e.g. `0x70011DC`, is there any IDAPython API that returns the function, e.g. `sub_0x7001024` which this address belong to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are looking for `GetFunctionName(ea)` from idc.

Here is a link to the API. The idc and idautils functions are preferable, since they are slightly more high-level: [API](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/)